# Gradle to define a filter for multiple use

Tags: java, gradle, build, copy

How to define a filter in gradle and use it inside multiple copy tasks?

The same set of replace tokens needed to be used for multiple copy tasks.Ho do i do it

Comment: You define a groovy (if using the groovy DSL) or a Kotlin (if using the Kotlin DSL) variable containing the tokens, and then use it every time you need it? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:declaring_variables

Comment: Thank you , I am using groovy dsl, since i am new to this a small example of the definition or a link depicting the same would be of great help

Comment: Read my comment. It has a link. You can click on it and read.

Comment: My bad ! Thanks ....A completely diff question , can i do the same technique  to define multiple folders where class files are present and use it as classpath in JavaCompile task

Comment: You shouldn't configure the JavaCompile task. The java plugin does that for you. The compile classpath is what you put in the `implementation` configuration. Please, read the documentation of the java plugin. Don't use "folders where classes are present". Use libraries published in a Maven repository.